# Have we ever seen an Atlantean sneeze underwater?

Tags: dc, aquaman, atlantis

The thought process behind this question is very simple, and a little bit silly:

- I was writing an answer about [how Atlanteans communicate underwater](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195684/98028);
- I sneezed;
- I realized I did not remember ever seeing a depiction of an Atlantean sneezing underwater.

Now the sneezing process for us normal air-breathers is pretty simple as I understand it: nose detects an intruder, stuff moves in there, muscles contract and the second after you expire a good chunk of air.

Atlanteans have roughly the same anatomy as humans, save for stuff in their throat that enable them to breathe water, talk, etc. So, I reckon the same sneezing process, with water instead of air, might be a possibility too.

**Is there a depiction of an Atlantean sneezing underwater?**

Scope is any DC material (comics first, TV shows, movies, novels even...).

Answer (score 2):

Aquaman sneezes in [Batman: The Brave and the Bold - *Bold Beginnings!*](https://braveandbold.fandom.com/wiki/Bold_Beginnings!) when he's trapped in an industrial freezer. As a minimum this demonstrates that Atlanteans (as a species) are capable of sneezing.

He comments that he's sorry, but

> "the ocean never gets this cold"

[image]